# Multiple apps using a single Azure Mobile Service for Live Authentication?

Tags: authentication, azure, live, azure-mobile-services

I have two separate apps and one Azure Mobile Service. Is there a way to link both apps to use Live Connection through the same Azure Mobile Service. The service allows associating one app to my Azure Mobile Service domain, but when I try to associate another app to the same service, I get an error that it is already in use (which is correct, but intended!).

1. One Azure Mobile Service
2. 2x Different Client Apps
3. Live Auth

Is there a way around this or am I forced to create a new mobile service for each app client type I have. This seems silly as they're all using the same back end service.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible.  If you look at the Identity settings for a Microsoft Account, one of the requirements is the Client ID which is tied to each individual Windows 8 app ID.